# Nlog :Repeating db records multiple times randomly while load is high

Tags: c#, wcf, nlog

I am facing a issue with log db while i am inserting records in db its inserting multiple times while in file the same record is in single time, while i am checking the trace file its showing the exact no that i am able to see in my db but reason i dint know, Can someone please look into that and do let me know what causing the issue.

I am attaching trace file and nlog.config file please review it and do let me know what causing the issue.

Please find the attachment here:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3770

Comment: What are you missing in the response, that you have already received? You should not use global NLog Config Variables `${var}` for context capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate Rolf's comment.

Small part of your config:

```xml
<parameter name="@ResponseCode" layout="${var:ResponseCode}" />
```

`${var}` is a global and isn't threadsafe. It not meant to change every logevent. There a other ways to send context to your database in a threadsafe way. See all options described [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context).

For this case probable the event properties is a good choice. You could use it like this:

```cs
logger.WithProperty("ResponseCode", responseCode).Info("Got response!");
```

Or structured logging style:

```
logger.Info("Got response with code {ResponseCode}!", responseCode);
```

And replace in your config `${var:ResponseCode}` with `${event-properties:ReponseCode}`